# Creating .htaccess file without it disappearing upon save (Mac OS)?

Tags: html, .htaccess

Title. I need to upload an htaccess file to my 1and1 webserver but as it's a dot file I can't save it.

Comment: Within your root directory there will be a folder called `.htaccess`. If not, then create one and place it within your root. Rewriting a URL requires move information from yourself.

Comment: Thank you i got that far and I know what to write in my htaccess file. How do I create an htaccess file on my system without it disapearring upon save?

Comment: It shouldn't disappear. It should just sit in your root folder. But if 1and1 are anything like GoDaddy they probably just hide it (due to security issues). There will be a few ways of accessing your files through 1and1 - I'm not sure what method you're using now but using an FTP or accessing through your cPanel should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is that you actually CAN save the file, but you just cannot see it.
By default, OSX hides some kind of file.

*To make these files visible you have 2 options:*

**1: Show just once**

- Go to the folder where you want to see the hidden files.
- Press `Cmd` + `Shift` + `.` (dot) in this folder.
- Run the same operation to turn it off, or simply close the tab.

**2: Show until you turn it off**

- Open the terminal
- Run this command: `$ defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true` followed by `$ killall Finder`
- To turn it off simply replace the `true` by `false` in the previous command.

Here you go, from now you should see all the hidden files you want.